# macOS native VPN can't cifs:// into file server on another network

Tags: network, osx-server, vpn

I have configured the macOS' native VPN to connect from location (a) to location (b), and now I would like to access the Thecus file storage server I have at location (b).

Accordingly, pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> in Finder and typing: `cifs://192.168.x.x` <-- server IP here.

to access the server I cannot connect, it just keeps trying to connect. Connecting from home it works, just not from one office to the other.

How can I get this to work? I have even tried afp://

Both endpoints are Mac devices if that helps.

Interestingly, both locations are on the same sub-net (192.168.X).

Is there a way to overcome this? I have a feeling that I may have to change the subnet of one of the offices.

Comment: The two networks have to be different: so either 192.168.0.0/24 at (a) and 192.168.1.0/24 at (b) or the other way round.

Comment: Klanomath I had thought as much. Is there no way around this?

Comment: Sure - but a lot of work and appropriate devices are required: [Connecting to a remote server through a VPN when the local network subnet address conflicts with a remote network](https://serverfault.com/a/557030/246265)

Comment: I have came across there earlier, think you have confirmed my suspicions

Answer (score 1):

Use smb:// for file shares and vnc:// for screen shares. I’ve not had good success with cifs:// and Finder.

If smb fails, check for open ports using network utility and look at the console on Mac and error log on the server/Linux/pc side. Network utility will show you if you have an ip / network conflict. The vpn possibly can’t route any traffic correctly if both non-routable networks conflict. Either the local or remote will have to change NAT range or move to IPv6.